# Access to thread-local storage (TLS) in GDB on Solaris

Tags: gdb, solaris, thread-local-storage

We have built GDB 7.12, from source, on various Unix platforms for process analysis.

We also use GDB to invoke a function in a "hung" process. We rely on thread local storage variables to achieve this. It works well on most Unix platforms.

We see the following message on Solaris (SunOS-5.11-i86pc-i386-64bit-ELF):

`(gdb) p mongo::mozjs::kCurrentScope
Cannot find thread-local variables on this target`

Is TLS supported on Solaris? Are there any workarounds?

[This bug](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=13677) seems to indicate it is not.

Comment: [`mdb` on Solaris can access thread-local storage](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18752_01/html/816-5041/exec-ctrl-11.html), so it's *possible*. `mdb` is extremely powerful, but - in my experience - hard to learn how to use. A quick look through [the Solaris Studio 12.4 `dbx` debugger documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37069_01/html/E37078/index.html) doesn't reveal any mentions of thread-local storage at all, which I find surprising given `mdb` supports it. I suspect `dbx` supports TLS, but have no direct knowledge of that.

Comment: What appears to be the original GDB thread discussing the addition of TLS support can be found at https://www.sourceware.org/ml/gdb/2002-06/msg00145.html.  There's some discussion about problems with Solaris at https://www.sourceware.org/ml/gdb/2002-06/msg00173.html, but I didn't dig through that post or its responses too much.  Given the age of the bug you listed, and the 2002 date of the GDB email discussion, I don't think it's much of a stretch to think GDB won't be supporting TLS on Solaris any time soon.